# Component diagram in JavafX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create diagram which shows different relations between components.

Something like this example:

[image]

Is there similar example or I hate to create custom component?

Comment: I havent seen one... And im always looking into new javafx stuff

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of an open source / free diagramming library for JavaFX (and I couldn't find one using google and the like). However, if you are willing to invest, there is a commercial JavaFX library for diagramming / graph visualization called [yFiles for JavaFX](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesjavafx_about.html). You can try the online demo browser on their homepage.

Comment: Is there other similar component library?

Comment: I don't know of one. Searching google reveals the said product as first hit. It is also a bit tedious to search for diagramming / graphs in JavaFX, because either you get irrelevant results for the chartdrawing part of JavaFX or information about the scene graph. If somebody can find other javafx graph drawing / diagramming libraries, I would be happy to hear about them.

Comment: Did you find any, @Sebastian ??

Comment: @AnaximandroAndrade I stumbled upon this a while ago: https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor It provides very basic graph editing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans Visual Library JavaFX port

https://github.com/theanuradha/visual-library-fx/releases

https://github.com/theanuradha/visual-library-fx/blob/master/org-netbeans-api-visualfx/src/test/java/test/graphlayout/GridGraphLayoutTest.java
[image]

NetBeans Visual Library : https://platform.netbeans.org/graph/.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwA4E1qESVc

Answer (score 0):

Try NetBeans Visual Library : https://platform.netbeans.org/graph/.

I don't know if it's implemented in JavaFX but it's compatible and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

VRL Studio might be what you need.

http://vrl-studio.mihosoft.eu/

Comment: I don't understand how this can be used with JavaFX?

Comment: Asked for javaFx integration. So negative vote

Answer (score 0):

It looks like FXDiagram might fit this need. It is described as "a framework for creating diagram tools based on JavaFX." The code is on github, but I could not find any license information.

http://jankoehnlein.github.io/FXDiagram/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a library, you can simply draw Shapes of the package javafx.scene.shape : Rectangle, Circle Text etc. You can also use SVGPath.
 These elements are easily modificable, draggable.

The other solution would be to use a Canvas, but this is much less flexible. (I discourage it)

The Container to include them is a group in the tutorial, I have also used it in a Region container.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0050__JavaFX_Rectangle.htm